# Inequality involving exponential

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading an analysis book which uses the following inequality, for  $x\le \frac{1}{16n}$: $$e^{-4x}(1-4\sqrt{nx})\ge e^{-8\sqrt{nx}}.$$ First, I thought of Taylor's theorem, but it's not. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Doubtful. If $x\to \frac{1}{16n}$ the lefthand side goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f(x,n)=e^{-4x}(1-4\sqrt{nx})- e^{-8\sqrt{nx}}$$ and let $x=\frac k {16n}$ with $0 < k <1$ to build the function
$$g(n,k)=\left(1-\sqrt{k}\right) e^{-\frac{k}{4 n}}-e^{-2 \sqrt{k}}$$ Since we want that $g(n,k)>0$ for any $n \geq 1$
$$g(1,k) >0 \qquad \implies \qquad k \leq 0.545\qquad \implies \qquad x \leq \frac 1 {30 n}$$

**Edit**

If you want to know $k$ such that the inequality holds for $n>m$, you just need to find the zero of
$$g(m,k)=\left(1-\sqrt{k}\right) e^{-\frac{k}{4 m}}-e^{-2 \sqrt{k}}$$ Expanded as series for large $m$
$$g(m,k)=\left(1-\sqrt{k}-e^{-2
   \sqrt{k}}\right)+\frac{\left(\sqrt{k}-1\right) k}{4
   m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$ and then an asymptotic value
$$k{\text{max}}=\frac{1}{4} \left(2+W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)\right)^2$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. Numerically
$$k_{\text{max}}=0.63491\qquad \implies \qquad x_{\text{max}}=\frac 1 {25 m}$$